# Python dict to YAML text doesn't preserve characters

Tags: python, dictionary, yaml, pyyaml

The question is simple but a bit tricky to phrase correctly.

Basically, I have a dictionary that has the following data:

```
x = { foo: [1, '\n', 'bar'] }
```

When I convert to yaml using pyyaml with `yaml.safe_dump(x, default_flow_style=False)` I expect the output to be:

```
foo:
  - 1
  - '\n'
  - bar
```

however, I'm getting something like

```
foo:
  - 1
  - '

    '
  - bar
```

The newline character is actually being interpreted instead of being passed as the '\n' string.

I have been looking at the pyyaml documentation but haven't seen the right incantations to have this thing parse correctly.

Has anyone dealt with this same issue before? How did you solve it?

---

To give more context, about this.

I have a json I want to convert to yaml.

The file that has something like this:

```
{ 
  "content": {
    "Fn::Join": ["\n", [{ "Ref": "parentStackName" }, ""]]
  }
}
```

the end result should be this:

```
content:
  Fn::Join:
    - "\n"
    - - Ref: parentStackId
      - ''
```

notice the `"\n"` is just a string there, and not an actual character.

The procedure I'm using is:

1. Open file
2. Parse json from text to dict
3. Use dict to dump to yaml

When I create the dict, you can see the "\n" as part of the string. It's when pyyaml dumps that into yaml that things go awry.

Comment: The string you've shown (`'\n'`) is a newline, not a literal backslash followed by a literal "n", so the YAML output you're getting makes perfect sense. Are you saying you want to convert characters like newline to their escape sequence representations? Or do you want your string to be `'\\n'` (literal backslash, literal "n")?

Comment: the string is a literal '\n', not a newline. I'm giving more context in the question.

Comment: `"\n"` in a JSON string represents a newline, not a literal backslash followed by a literal "n" (see the [spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-404.pdf)). So you're getting the expected result.

Comment: Please note that in YAML output this `'\n'` is completely different from `"\n"`. In my answer I have assumed that you want the second version.

Comment: Why not use `r'\n'` instead of `'\n'` in `x`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the output you want, you can use the round-trip capabilities of [ruamel.yaml](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ruamel.yaml/), and update the flow-style that the JSON subset of YAML uses to block style:

```
import sys
import ruamel.yaml
from ruamel.yaml.comments import CommentedMap, CommentedSeq

# because this is a string and not read from file, you need to escape 
# the backslash in \n
json_str = """\
{
  "content": {
    "Fn::Join": ["\\n", [{ "Ref": "parentStackName" }, ""]]
  }
}
"""  


def block_style(base):
    """set all mapping and sequneces to block-style"""
    if isinstance(base, CommentedMap):
        for k in base:
            block_style(base[k])
        base.fa.set_block_style()
    if isinstance(base, list):
        for item in base:
            block_style(item)
        base.fa.set_block_style()
    return base


data = ruamel.yaml.round_trip_load(json_str)
block_style(data)
ruamel.yaml.round_trip_dump(data, sys.stdout)
```

gives:

```
content:
  Fn::Join:
  - "\n"
  - - Ref: parentStackName
    - ''
```

`ruamel.yaml` is an updated version of PyYAML (disclaimer: I am the author). It supports the YAML 1.2 spec (from 2009) which brings YAML more in line with being a full superset of JSON and allows you to read your JSON with the ruamel.yaml parser (PyYAML only supports most of the YAML 1.1 spec).

In "round-trip-mode", the enhancements of `ruamel.yaml` include maintaining the flow- resp. block-style of the composite nodes (mappings and sequences) on an individual basis (as well as various quoting styles, comments and tag names). What `block_style()` does is recursively change the "flow-attribute" `.fa` to be block style for all composite nodes.

Comment: excellent, this does exactly what I needed. It also keeps the order of the attributes :)  Great work!

Answer (score -1):

Use *raw strings* when the string includes special characters:

```
$ cat /tmp/tmp.py

import yaml

foo = 'foo'
x = { foo: [1, r'\n', 'bar'] }
y = yaml.safe_dump(x, default_flow_style=False)
print(y)

$ python3 /tmp/tmp.py
foo:
- 1
- \n
- bar
```